# Wordpress Dropdown that shows ONLY sibling categories

Tags: wordpress, categories, siblings

I have a dropdown displaying all the blog categories and their children. Now my coworker thinks it would be a good idea to filter to display ONLY sibling categories. Not parent categories or child categories from other parents. ONLY sibling categories.

Ive dug around found literally nothing, so I am opening this thread.

things I have already tried: walker classes. this sounds promising but since the WP documentation has literally nothing about it, it is hard to know if that would work or not. im leaning towards not but again, its hard to say.

```
 <?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=Select a Category&hierarchical=1' ); ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 <!--
 var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
 function onCatChange() {
 if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
 location.href = "<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
 }
 }
 dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
 -->
 </script>
```

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code you've tried previously, or are using currently to get and display this dropdown?

Comment: this describes how to do what i am looking to accomplish, somewhat. I need to do it with categories, not pages, and mine will not be based off admin created menus, but rather dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories( array(
    'show_option_none' => "Select a Category",
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'child_of' => get_the_category()[0]->term_id,
    'depth' => 1 
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `wp_dropdown_categories()` call to include only pages that are children of the current page's parent category, and adjust your `depth` parameter to not show any children of siblings.

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories( array(
    'show_option_none' => "Select a Category",
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'child_of' => get_the_category()[0]->category_parent, // get the idea of the parent category for the current page/post
    'depth' => 1 // limit the depth of the heirarchy to only the current level
)); ?>
```

Behaviors are well-documented on the [function reference page for `wp_dropdown_categories()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories).

Comment: it is throwing this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WP_Term::category_parent() in /Users/bluepreston/sites/redislabs/wp-content/themes/redislabs/single.php:84 Stack trace: #0

Comment: @PrestonReyes My mistake - there shouldn't be any parenthesis next to `category_parent`, as it's not a method but rather a property - please see my edit.

Comment: that is outputting the the parents, but i need just the siblings. thanks so much, this is forward progress.

Comment: If that's actually the case, just remove the `[0]->category_parent` from the `'child_of' => get_the_category()[0]->category_parent` line

Comment: that renders an error "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/bluepreston/sites/redislabs/wp-content/themes/redislabs/single.php on line 103"

Comment: it needed term_id rather than category_parent. thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This very useful. If you have a multiple category list and you want to show only the child categories of the parent category then you have to use it.

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories( array(
    'show_option_none' => "Select a Category",
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'child_of' => get_the_category()[0]->category_parent, // get the idea of the parent category for the current page/post
    'depth' => 1 // limit the depth of the heirarchy to only the current level
)); ?>
```